# why %d for a pointer to an array gives me the first element of the array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Can someone please explain to me why this code always returns the first element of the array? (7 in this example):

```
int a[] = {7,1,3};
printf("%d", *a);
```

Comment: Please explain why it should not.

Comment: This should be explained in the chapter about arrays and pointers in your C programming book.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Arrays are not pointers. Please don't use that oversimplification that causes endless confusion and misery to beginners.

Comment: I see no "*pointer to an array*".

Comment: Doing `*a` is the same as  doing `*(a+0)` is the same as doing `a[0]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, let me tell you, there is **no *pointer to array* here**, all you have is an array variable, with dereference operator applied to it.

Arrays, (*among many other cases*) when used as the operand of the `*` operators, decay to the pointer to the first element of the array <sup>**Note**</sup>. So

```
 printf("%d", *a);
```

is the same as

```
 printf("%d", *(&(a[0]));
```

after that, as per `printf()` requirement,

- You have a `%d` conversion specifier
- You have an argument of type `int`

So, it prints the value properly.

---

Note:

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1, *Lvalues, arrays, and function designators*, (*emphasis mine*)

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. [...]

Answer (score 10):

It's not the `"%d"` format that give you the first element, it's the dereference operator when used with the array.

Arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, and when you dereference a pointer you get the value it points to.

Answer (score 4):

`*a` will always return first index of the array. it has nothing to do with `%d`.

```
*a  // returns 7
*(a + 1) // returns 1
*(a + 2) // returns 3
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Exactly. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the **initial
>   element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. If the array
>   object has register storage class, the behavior is undeﬁned.

and (6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators)

> 4 The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a
>   function, the result is a function designator; **if it points to an
>   object, the result is an lvalue designating the object.** If the
>   operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. If
>   an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the
>   unary * operator is undeﬁned.

Thus in this statement

```
printf("%d", *a);
```

the array `a` in the expression `*a` is converted to pointer to its first element and applying the unary operator * yields the object (the first element of the array) pointed to by the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%d", *a);
```

*a is equivalent to *(a+0); which gives you the first element of the array
and is also equivalent to a[0];

a is the address of the array.Imagine the array starts from address 0x00;
a+0 gives you the same number since you increment it by 0.If you write a+1 you get 0x04 if int is 4 bytes.Addig * simply dereference it.Finally you get the number with offset of 4 which is the second int element in the array.

```
-----------------------------------------
|          7        |         1         |
-----------------------------------------
|0x00|0x01|0x02|0x03|0x04|0x05|0x06|0x07|
```

Answer (score 2):

Coming from the embedded background I always think of data in physical terms. So every physical thing has 2 basic feature attached to it.

1. What? (That's the value of the variable).
2. Where? (The physical address where the variable is stored).

Now when you declare the array you created a list of variables in stack with name "a", where "a" is telling the start of where part (the address of array)

When you use use

```
printf("%d", *a);
```

you are actually asking the program to go to starting of array, which yeilds you value 7.

"a" is basically a name which you gave to the array of numbers, and it always points to the start of array and hence when you directly acess it it gives you first value.